# nginx mod_zip does not calculate checksum for upstream files

Tags: nginx, zip, crc, crc32, nginx-module

When using mod_zip for nginx you can specify `-` as the checksum for a file if it's unknown. Mod_zip will calculate the checksum for files on local block storage and add it automatically, but if the file comes from an upstream subrequesst the checksums are recorded as  `000000`.

Can mod_zip be configured to generate crc32 for upstream/subrequest files?

Comment: Do you mean the [`mod_zip`](https://github.com/evanmiller/mod_zip) third party plugin by Evan Miller?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: I'm afraid there are a little chances to get an answer on SO, this is not a widely used module. Why not to ask the developer directly on GitHub?